# git clone fail on network filesystem

Tags: git, cifs

I have setup an ssh client with .ssh/config data und want local PC use an mountet cifs Filesystem
User can write on cifs , but
clone fails if user is in mountet dir:

```
git clone ssh://git/*#+*/bricktech.git bricktech

Cloning into '/mnt/dira/dir-01/FRITZ/bricktech'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 27, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Total 27 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: --stdin requires a git repository
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

git version 2.31.1

if the user in the home dir

```
git clone ssh://git/*#+*/bricktech.git bricktech
Klone nach 'bricktech' ...
remote: Enumerating objects: 27, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Total 27 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Empfange Objekte: 100% (27/27), 15.64 KiB | 5.21 MiB/s, fertig.
Löse Unterschiede auf: 100% (4/4), fertig.
```

works .....

/etc/fstab:

> serverip/dir /mnt/fb-jahn cifs username=****,password=*****,vers=1.0,gid=100,uid=1000,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,noauto,users  0 0

maybe wrong mode ??

Comment: Can you run that command (the failed one) setting language to english? Like `LANG=en git clone ssh://git/*#+*/bricktech.git bricktech` so that we get english output. (In my case, you can also use LANG=es, but I don't think that will hold water here either XD).

Comment: '''Cloning into 'bricktech'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 27, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
fatal: --stdin requires a git repository
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output'''

Answer (score 0):

The error message translates to "not a Git repository", which is coming from commands that `git clone` runs after writing the various Git files to create a new, empty Git repository, followed by reading data from the remote Git to get pack files to put into the new repository to make it non-empty.

The fact that `git index-pack` *believes* that the new Git repository is *not* a Git repository indicates that the underlying file system is not working correctly.  It's not possible to say, from this alone, *what about* the underlying file system isn't working correctly, but CIFS / Samba [has been reported to work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11240817/1256452).  Other users say [there are problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37051071/1256452).

Note that while SMB (or Samba) is not CIFS, it is something of a superset.  I avoid Windows and don't know if anyone actually uses raw CIFS any more.  A lot may depend on your particular server, which you did not mention.

(SSH itself is not relevant here, and I removed the [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) tag.)

Comment: the server is an AVM FRITZ Router - and there ist only version 1.0 SMB implementet - i think i try  ftp :-) the other supportet protokoll - or go over an external USB Drive ... or just buy an Raspberry and run it as an NAS ....

Comment: mount curl ftp - fails - other filesystem other error :-) Cloning into 'bricktech'...
error: Unable to create '/mnt/fb-jahn/bricktech/.git/HEAD.lock': Operation not supported